# Is this smart test params critical?

Tags: hard-drive

I have bought HDD Toshiba MG 12tb MG07ACA12TE in open plactic box.

On my hdd I see the production date: **05-15-2019**

When I checked my s/n on toshiba site I saw **Exp Date: 2021/06/17**

Here my smart test

```
G-Sense_Error_Rate — 1 
Disk_Shift — 6
```

I understand someone dropped hdd.

Is this critical?

Full Test

```
C:\Windows\system32>smartctl -a /dev/sda

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Toshiba MG07ACA... Enterprise Capacity HDD
Device Model:     TOSHIBA MG07ACA12TE
Serial Number:    59E0A0T1F95G
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000039 968caa99a
Firmware Version: 0101
User Capacity:    12 000 138 625 024 bytes [12,0 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Form Factor:      3.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 5
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.3, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sat May 16 10:47:25 2020 RTZST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x84) Offline data collection activity
                                        was suspended by an interrupting command from host.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline
data collection:                (  120) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (1228) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                                        SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                                        SCT Feature Control supported.
                                        SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0005   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   100   100   001    Pre-fail  Always       -       6781
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       448
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000b   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0005   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   091   091   000    Old_age   Always       -       3643
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0033   100   100   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       31
 23 Helium_Condition_Lower  0x0023   100   100   075    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 24 Helium_Condition_Upper  0x0023   100   100   075    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       3
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       882
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       38 (Min/Max 21/44)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
220 Disk_Shift              0x0002   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       393216
222 Loaded_Hours            0x0032   092   092   000    Old_age   Always       -       3235
223 Load_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
224 Load_Friction           0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
226 Load-in_Time            0x0026   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       531
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0001   100   100   001    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%        39         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%         3         -
# 3  Extended offline    Aborted by host               90%         3         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

220 Disk_Shift 6  - says Victoria Smart

Comment: I am not familiar with these two parameters.

Comment: but posting a whole test instead of 2 parameters would be more helpful to judge.
Try running smartmontools and run
smartcl -a /dev/sdX > C.\mylog.txt
Replace "X" by the label of the drive in question and post the content of mylog.txt

Comment: @r2d3  Thanks, for reply. I post full output. Can you check pls. I would be very appreciate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the two figures you already mentioned where one "disk shift" has gone up there is no sign of degradation.

To verify if the figure "G-Sense_Error_Rate" has affected the surface you could duplicate the drive using ddrescue either into another drive or into the zero device.
Use and keep the log file and make a screen shot after ddrescue ends because this will give you a summary of errors and a detailed list with possible errors (log file).

It's up to you to check the mechanical setup of your drive with regards to the increasing  "disk shift" parameter.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do this!